# How to set chipText on com.google.android.material.chip.Chip?

Tags: android, android-chips

I am investigating the material components provided by

```
implementation group: 'com.google.android.material', name: 'material', version: '1.0.0-alpha3'
```

namely `com.google.android.material.chip.Chip`

Using Android Studio version

```
Android Studio 3.2 Canary 18
Build #AI-181.4892.42.32.4830125, built on June 8, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b04 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Mac OS X 10.11.6
```

I created a basic application with this gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'android-P'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.research.peanut"
        minSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.1'

    implementation group: 'com.google.android.material', name: 'material', version: '1.0.0-alpha3'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha3'
}
```

Following this [site](https://material.io/develop/android/components/chip/)

I added the following chips to my layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:chipText="@string/hello_world" />

    <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Entry"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:chipIcon="@drawable/ic_add_circle_outline_24dp"
        app:chipText="@string/hello_world" />

    <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Filter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:chipText="@string/hello_world" />

    <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Choice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:chipText="@string/hello_world"/>


    <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Action"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:chipIcon="@drawable/ic_call_to_action_24dp"
        app:chipText="@string/hello_world"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I get have the following build issues

```
Android resource linking failed
Output:  /Users/frankb/AndroidStudioCanaryProjects/wip/Peanut/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml:10: error: attribute chipText (aka com.research.peanut:chipText) not found.
/Users/frankb/AndroidStudioCanaryProjects/wip/Peanut/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml:15: error: attribute chipText (aka com.research.peanut:chipText) not found.
/Users/frankb/AndroidStudioCanaryProjects/wip/Peanut/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml:22: error: attribute chipText (aka com.research.peanut:chipText) not found.
/Users/frankb/AndroidStudioCanaryProjects/wip/Peanut/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml:28: error: attribute chipText (aka com.research.peanut:chipText) not found.
/Users/frankb/AndroidStudioCanaryProjects/wip/Peanut/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml:35: error: attribute chipText (aka com.research.peanut:chipText) not found.
error: failed linking file resources.
```

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

when a change my gradle dependency to

```
implementation group: 'com.google.android.material', name: 'material', version: '1.0.0-alpha1'
```

My app works fine.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue after updating it to `1.0.0-alpha03`. Setting `chipText` programatically works btw.

Comment: @Nominalista, when I set chip text programatically the displayed chip text is not displayed correctly as the chips size (width) is set as if it has no text. How are you getting the text displayed in full?

Comment: Are you calling setChiptText or setText? The second one results in weird behaviour.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Version `1.0.0-beta01` came out, and the text can now be set through `android:text`

Answer (score 2):

Just because the Chips `extends` Button and then `TextView` we are able to use

```
<android.support.design.chip.Chip
 .
 .
android:text="text"/>
```